# In Umbraco, how can I bind a generic list of Objects to my View?

Tags: c#, generics, umbraco, umbraco7

Something strange is happening in my umbraco project where I have a repository set up like so;

```
public class HireItemsRepo:BaseGenericRepository<YouHireItContext,HireItem>
{
   public List<HireItemViewModel> PopulateHireItemViewModel(RenderModel model)
    { List<HireItemViewModel> HireItems = new List<HireItemViewModel>();   
        foreach (var Hireitem in base.GetAll())
        {
            HireItems.Add(
              new HireItemViewModel(model.Content)
              {
                  Title = Hireitem.Title,
                  Price = Hireitem.Price
              }
           );
        }
        return HireItems;
    }

}
```

which I'm using in my controller like this

```
 public class HiresController : RenderMvcController
    {
        // GET: Hire
        public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
        {

            HireItemsRepo repo = new HireItemsRepo();
            var VM = repo.PopulateHireItemViewModel(model);

                return View("Hires",VM.ToList());
        }
    }
```

And using that model in the view like this;

```
    @model List<You_Hire_It.Models.HireItemViewModel>

   /*HTML starts here*/
```

It's strange because if I try to use that model as a List, Umbraco will blow up with the following error;

*Cannot bind source type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[You_Hire_It.Models.HireItemViewModel, You_Hire_It, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] to model type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel.*

However, if I refactor all the code to use the model on it's own as if I only have one set of values to use, it has no problem with it!

Could anybody point me in the right direction with this please?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit from RenderModel as DZL suggests.  However, I generally prefer to use route hijacking which would enable me to keep my models simple.

Instead of the `Index` method in your RenderMvcController, you can create a method with the same name as your view.  I note your view is called `Hires`. So change your controller code to this:

```
public class HiresController : RenderMvcController
{
    // GET: Hire
    public ActionResult Hires(RenderModel model)
    {
        HireItemsRepo repo = new HireItemsRepo();
        var VM = repo.PopulateHireItemViewModel(model);

        return CurrentTemplate(VM)
    }
}
```

You now need to have your view inherit from `UmbracoViewPage`. So at the top of your view replace the `@model` line with the following:

```
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<List<HireItemViewModel>>
```

Your model in the view is now of type `List<HireItemViewModel>` which I think is what you want.

So to iterate the items you would use:

```
@foreach(var item in Model){
{
    // etc
}
```

Additionally, as this view now inherits from `UmbracoViewPage`, you have access to the `UmbracoContext` - just use `@Umbraco`

For example:

```
@Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().Where(x=>x.DocumentTypeAlias == "HomePage")
```

or

```
@Umbraco.AssignedContentItem etc
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the model you return from the action need to be of type `RenderModel` or inherit from it and in your case you are returning a `List`.
So your model should look something like this:

```
public class ViewModel : RenderModel
{
    public ViewModel(IPublishedContent content) : base(content) { }

    public List<HireItem> HireItems { get; set; }
}

public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
{
    var vm = new ViewModel(model);
    vm.HireItems = new HireItemsRepo().GetHireItems();
    return View("Hires", vm);
}
```